# How to send a string to the terminal without having it to be a standard command?

Tags: java, process, terminal, command

I am writing a program in Java that needs to use terminal command to work.
My function basically looks like this :

```
public void sendLoginCommand() throws IOException
{
    System.out.println("\n------------Sending Login Command------------\n");
    String cmd="qskdjqhsdqsd";
    Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
    Process p=rt.exec(cmd);
}
public Process sendPassword(String password) throws IOException
{
    System.out.println("\n------------Sending Password------------\n");
    String cmd=password;
    Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
    Process p=rt.exec(cmd);
    return p;
}
public void login(String password) throws IOException
{
    sendLoginCommand();
    Process p = sendPassword(password);
    System.out.println("\n------------Reading Terminal Output------------\n");
    Reader in = new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream());

    in = new BufferedReader(in);
    char[] buffer = new char[20];
    int len = in.read(buffer);
    String s = new String(buffer, 0, len);
    System.out.println(s);
    if(s.equals("Password invalid.")) loggedIn=false;
    else loggedIn=true;
}
```

Here, the program sends correctly th p4 login command, but then, the terminal asks for a password.
When I use the same lines that with the sendLoginCommand(), the program returns an error.
Apparently, we can send only standard commands throught Process.
I was hoping that someone knew how to send a normal string to the terminal

Thank you in advance

Comment: I must say well done for the mess you've done there. You are actually trying to start processes by using login and then password as the command line that starts that process. This is completely wrong, all the way.

Comment: No, here, the "main" function is login(). First, it calls sendlogincommand() which successfully sends the command, but when the next function sendpassword() is called, i can't send the password because it is not a command. And also, you might say that the command "qsdqsdsdkqsdq" is not a command, well it is true, the original command was "p4 login"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the answer to my question.

The problem was that the second response of the terminal was in fact in the first one, and the password had to be sent in the middle of it.
Here is the code (I agree, my explanation is a little vague) :

```
    String s="";
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("p4 login");     
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));    
    char a=(char)in.read();
    while(a>0 && a<256)
    {

        a=(char)in.read();
        if(nb==14) new PrintWriter(p.getOutputStream(),true).println(password); 
        if(nb>16) s=s+a;
        nb++;
    }
    if(s.startsWith("User")) loggedIn=true;
    else loggedIn=false;
```

Answer (score 3):

Your immediate problem is that you are starting separate processes for each of the 'commands' you are invoking. The password 'command' is being issued to a process that is totally unaware of the previous 'login' command.

Having said that, your more dire problem is a serious misunderstanding of what the Process class is used for and how to interact with external programs from within Java.

Here's one [tutorial](http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-run-another-application-from-java.html) that may help further your education on the topic, I would advise Googling for others.

Answer (score 0):

In order to communicate with a process, you don't start another process but write to its stdin. There's actually code in there that tries to do such a thing. Have `sendLoginCommand` return the created process; delete all code in `sendPassword`, in fact delete the whole method. In your main code write your password to the process's output stream. So what I'm saying is

```
new PrintWriter(sendLoginCommand().getOutputStream()).println(password);
```

Comment: I don't understand what I am supposed to do with p.getOutputStream() and the PrintWriter. Could you detail a little bit please?

Comment: Actually I'm sorry, it does not work. I thought it did because not errors were return but new PrintWriter(sendLoginCommand().getOutputStream()).println(password); does absolutely nothing, because when I try to retreive the output of the terminal afterwards, I get "Enter password", which is the output of the previous command : "p4 login"

Comment: Well, of course it is the output of that command! You are still not getting te basic principles. You have **spawned a process** calling 'Runtime.exec` and now you are communicating with it over its stdout and stdin. The process prints "Enter password" and that is what you read. The fact that you read it **after** having already sent the password doesn't change a thing. There is a possibility, though, that you are sending password too quickly. Try to first read the line saying "enter password", then send password.

Comment: How can the fact that I read "Enter Password" be possible even after I have sent the password? Because my program needs to be able to read the output of the terminal after I have sent the password to know if it is correct or not

Comment: It is possible due to buffering. The moment your `p4` process executes code that outputs that string is not at all the same moment when your Java code reads it. Think about it, how would that be even possible?

Comment: I agree on the fact that I can not read at the same moment, but even when I wait after I have sent "p4 login" before I retreive the output, I still have "Enter Password" and I can't even be able to say if the password has been sent

Comment: The program prints "Enter password" to its stdout and that's what you read. It doesn't matter how late you read it, you'll always get in sequence what that program sent to its stdout. It's a pipe. The only problem with timing can be that the receiving end ignores any input that it can read from its stdin at a certain moment (it *flushes* its input stream). But if you successfully read "enter password" and then write the password, you can be sure the other end got that. One last issue is that you need to *flush* your output to be sure that it actually went to the other side (buffering again).

Comment: So how can I read the output of the terminal after the password has been sent?

Comment: Just continue reading from the input pipe. If nothing's coming in, that means that nothing is being sent from the other end.

Comment: I already read and read again after submitting the password, but always nothing. And when I type this command on the terminal directly, it is almost instant. I guess new PrintWriter(sendLoginCommand().getOutputStream()).println(password) does not do anything

Comment: And what about flushing? I have mentioned it more than two times by now.

Comment: Even with flushing, there still is nothing

Comment: You have probably made enough progress by now to formulate a new question with your improved code and ask SO to help you with the specific problem you have now. See you on that question. As far as this one, it would be fair if you accepted this answer as an acknowledgment of my assistance so far.

Answer (score 0):

As a side note, i strongly advice to use a pre-packaged library that already encapsulates all the technical stuff about the process communication in Java.

A good library about that is **commons-exec** (http://commons.apache.org/exec/.

It comes with command line helper, background thread to read the sysout/syserr output, an optional watchdog to kill the process after a given amount of time, and so on (it works of course on nearly all os).