# How to send non-command data to the terminal from a JAVA program?

Tags: java, terminal, command, send

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to send a string to the terminal without having it to be a standard command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10315880/how-to-send-a-string-to-the-terminal-without-having-it-to-be-a-standard-command)

I have already posted a question on this topic, but after a little while, I still have my problem unsolved. Marko Topolnik has showed me some possible answers, but I am still blocked.

Here is my problem :

I have a Java program that needs, at some point, to connect to an external program.
To do so, I implemented the following function:

```
public void login(String password) throws IOException
{
    final Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("p4 login");
    final BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
    System.out.println("going to read line");

    System.out.println(in.read());
    System.out.println("read line");
    new PrintWriter(p.getOutputStream(),true).println(password);
    System.out.println("password sent");
    String line;
    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null)      
    {      
        System.out.println("printing line");
        System.out.println(in.read());
        System.out.println(line);
        System.out.println("printed line");
        if (line.startsWith("User")) loggedIn=true;
    }        
    loggedIn=false;
}
```

This function successfully sends "p4 login" to the terminal.
The response from the terminal at this point is : "Enter Password:"

Then, I tried to send the password to the terminal, but I couldn't find a way to do so. I have tried using the same command as for the first time, but the exec command can only send standart commands.

This was the problem of my [first post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10315880/how-to-send-a-string-to-the-terminal-without-having-it-to-be-a-standard-command): I was sending the password with the exec() command, that is why I have tried with

```
new PrintWriter(p.getOutputStream()).println(password);
```

The System.out.println(s); in my function always displays "Enter Password:", which is not what I am looking for.

I have tried flushing the output, which has been suggested to me in my older post, wait a while between the first command sent and the second, but still nothing.

If somebody knows how I could do such thing, it would be great.

Comment: But if this is the same problem, you should go back to that problem, and fix that, not just re-ask the question? If this question is different, please make that clear

Comment: Yes indeed, this is almost a duplicate, but my last question was not answered, and it has been suggested to me to post again

Comment: Hmm, you might want to give the old question some love then. Accept an answer, explain here what the difference is (e.g. what you had, where you are now and what your new question is).

Comment: I directed OP to post a new question because there were completely different problems solved there. He claimed that now he has updated the code and written it so that the output buffer was being flushed, but he still had no success. Now I look at this code, and still no evidence of flushing -- so still the same problem, which is, **no flushing**. OP, please show us the code that flushes the buffer!

Answer (score 0):

This code is going to loop forever, but it's going to print out whatever the program is sending you:

```
public boolean login(String password) throws Exception {
  final Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("p4 login");
  final BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
  final char[] buf = new char[20];
  System.out.println(new String(buf, 0, in.read(buf)));
  System.out.println("Sending password");
  new PrintWriter(p.getOutputStream(),true).println(password);
  System.out.println("Password sent");
  int read;
  while ((read = in.read(buf)) != -1) {
    System.out.print(new String(buf, 0, read));
    System.out.flush();
  }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: I have edited my function, but the problem remains. The output is still "Enter Password:"

Comment: Have you written any code to read past the first line of that process's output? Have you reordered code so you first read in "Enter password", then send the password? I'm not talking to you until you update your code in this question so it reflects this advice.

Comment: I read your code again and now I see your real problem. You cannot open two Readers on the same InputStream, that will mess up buffering and potentially other stuff. So, after you have your `Reader in`, use that reader throughout the rest of the code. Plus, call `in.readLine` to read one line at a time. Your code expects exactly 20 characters to be read and won't go on until it gets those 20 chars. `readLine` is a method on `BufferedReader` so your `in` var must be of that type. See edited answer.

Comment: I'm sorry but it still doesn't work, the second print displays nothing

Comment: Edit the question and copy-paste your new code.

Comment: I just couldn't use the readLine function, I couldn't find it

Comment: There, now I posted the complete code of your method.

Comment: The code you posted doesn't seem to work. The program seems to get stuck in a while loop and keeps running. It doesn't even print the first response of the terminal

Comment: Which one, "Enter Password"? So that's not a complete line, then.

Comment: Yes, "Enter password:" is not displayed

Comment: The code only displays "going to read line", and then get stuck

Comment: So you're communicating with a service that doesn't end the line you want to read. This is very fragile communication then. I'll post a workaround that first uses the char buffer and then switches to reading lines. Hopefully the rest of that program's output are normal lines. If not, you are in a lot of trouble.

Comment: I don't know if it relevant, but when I type "p4 login" in the terminal, the password I enter afterwards is invisible. Meaning that when I type a letter, it is not displayed on the terminal

Comment: That's classic unix behavior. And that output "Password: " is not followed by a newline. It shouldn't be a problem that the password is not displayed.

Comment: Now, the output of my program is : "going to read line 16 read line"

Comment: Why don't you print what you've actually read, instead of the number of chars read? You read 16 chars, that corresponds probably to "Enter password: ". Then you get stuck and no more lines are read. But ensure exactly where you are blocking. Print something after sending the password, so at least that is confirmed. If readLine still blocks, we can try again reading with read(char[]), but then you can't reliably detect "User" in the input.

Comment: Now, the output is: going to read line / 69 / read line / password sent / printing line / -1 / nter password:  / printed line

Comment: The readLine() actually worked in the while conditions, but kept only the previous output without the first letter

Comment: Your code is quite a mess now. You are reading a line, then reading a char (that `in.read()`) in your code, so no wonder the first char is missing. Please take my code as it is now. I just edited it, you must see "sedning password" and "password sent" in there. You should REALLY get in the habit of reading Javadoc of methods you are calling!

Comment: Your code displays sending password and password sent, but never goes in the loop because read takes instantly value -1. This means that the terminal doesn't send anything back to check if the user has loggedIn

Comment: Or, new PrintWriter(p.getOutputStream(),true).println(password); does not send anything to the terminal

Comment: The value -1 means that the process closed its output and ended. The `println` either successfully sends the password into the process or throws an IOException.